# how to add annotate data in django-rest-framework queryset responses?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am generating aggregates for each item in a QuerySet:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    from django.db.models import Count
    queryset = Book.objects.annotate(Count('authors'))
    return queryset
```

But I am not getting the count in the JSON response.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The queryset returned from get_queryset provides the list of things that will go through the serializer, which controls how the objects will be represented. Try adding an additional field in your Book serializer, like:

```
author_count = serializers.IntegerField(
    source='author_set.count', 
    read_only=True
)
```

**Edit:** As others have stated, this is not the most efficient way to add counts for cases where many results are returned, as it will hit the database for each instance. See the answer by @José for a more efficient solution.

Comment: For me, this answer is also very useful to calculate the number of posts of a single tag. thanks you!

Answer (score 97):

The accepted solution will hit the database as many times as results are returned. For each result, a `count` query to the database will be made.

The question is about adding annotations to the serializer, which is way more effective than doing a `count` query for each item in the response.

A solution for that:

**models.py**

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    other_stuff = models...
    ...

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    title = models.CharField(...)
    publication_year = models...
    ...
```

**serializers.py**

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    authors = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'authors')
```

**views.py**

```
class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Book.objects.annotate(authors=Count('author'))
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    ...
```

That will make the counting at database level, avoiding to hit database to retrieve authors count for each one of the returned `Book` items.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to use the BookViewSet class once created? I am trying to achieve the same results but once I have the ViewSet, I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: `serializers.IntegerField()` needs have `read_only=True` i suppose.

Comment: Can you please look at this as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74174749/django-queryset-with-matches-for-multiple-related-objects

Answer (score 8):

Fiver's solution will hit the db for every instance in the queryset so if you have a large queryset, his solution will create a lot of queries.

I would override the ***to_representation*** of your Book serializer, it reuses the result from the ***annotation***. It will look something like:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     def to_representation(self, instance):
        return {'id': instance.pk, 'num_authors': instance.authors__count}

    class Meta:
        model = Book
```

Comment: Can you pls explain - why Fiver's solution would generate a lot of queries? I thought the serializer field will be processed after queryset is executed, which will do proper join/grouping?

Comment: I made it with `Field(source='annotated_field')`

Comment: @DmitrySemenov I think the source argument will reference a method not a variable. I had "source='author_set.count'" on my code before but it turned out generating a lot of queries (you can see it from the debugger), most of the queries were repeated, and called the count method.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you make an annotation like

```
Model.objects.annotate(
    some_new_col=Case(
        When(some_field=some_value, then=Value(something)),
        # etc...
        default=Value(something_default),
        output_field=SomeTypeOfField(),
    )
).filter()#etccc
```

and the interpreter throws in an error that `something` is not a model field for the related `serializer`, there is a workaround. It's not nice but if you add a method `some_new_col`, it recognizes the value from the query above.
The following will do just fine.

```
def some_new_col(self):
    pass;
```

Answer (score 0):

Im doing it in elegant way in DRF, creating custom model manager

```
## models.py
from . import custom_managers

class MyModel(models.Model):
    field=...
    #
    objects=models.Manager()   # default model manager  MyModel.objects.all()
    annotate_objects=custom_managers.MyModelSummary()

## custom_managers.py

class MyModelSummary(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = (super().get_queryset()
                    .values('date__month','date__year')
                    .annotate(total=models.Count('price'))
                    .annotate(sum=models.Sum('price'))
                    .order_by('date__year','date__month')
                    .values('date__month',
                            'date__year',
                            'total',
                            'sum')
                    )
        return queryset
        
## summary_serializers.py

class MyModelSummarySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    month=serializers.IntegerField(source='date__month')
    year=serializers.IntegerField(source='date__year')
    total=serializers.IntegerField()
    sum=serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields =['month','year','total','sum']

## summery_views.py

class MyModelSummaryListView(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset=MyModel.annotate_objects.all()
    serializer_class=MyModelSummarySerializer
```