# DjangoRestFramework: Unable to return count in JSON Response

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-1.9

I've a table Orders which contains ID, store_name, order_date, ..... I want to create an endpoint which returns me the JSON which consists of Count of Orders from all the Stores. Something as follows:

```
[{store_name: 'Target', count: 10}, {store_name: 'Walmart', count: 20}, {store_name: 'Costco', count: 5}]
```

The query I wrote is:

```
queryset = Stores.objects.all().values('store_name').annotate(total=Count('store_name'))
```

When I print queryset, I'm getting what I need as mentioned above.
But when I serialize the data, I get the following:

```
[{store_name: 'Target'}, {store_name: 'Walmart'}, {store_name: 'Costco'}]
```

Not sure what am I doing wrong.. I've included my code. (I'm not including import statements)

serializer.py

```
class StoresSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Stores
        exclude = ['order_date',]
```

views.py

```
class StoresViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Stores.objects.all().values('store_name').annotate(total=Count('store_name'))
    serializer_class = StoresSerializer
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Check that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434425/how-to-add-annotate-data-in-django-rest-framework-queryset-responses

Answer (score 0):

Using [one old topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434425/how-to-add-annotate-data-in-django-rest-framework-queryset-responses) it would go as follows

models.py (simplified version just to demonstrate the idea)

```
class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Order(models.Model):
    store_name = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

serializer.py

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Store

class StoresSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    orders = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = ('name', 'orders')
```

views.py

```
class StoresViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Store.objects.all().values('name').annotate(orders=Count('order'))
    serializer_class = StoresSerializer
```