# Django - How to update a field for a model on another model's creation?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models, a Product model and a Rating model. What I want to accomplish is, every time a "Rating" is created, via an API POST to an endpoint created using DRF, I want to compute and update the `average_rating` field in the associated Product.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...
    average_rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Rating(models.Model):
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', related_name='ratings')

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.rating)
```

What is the best way to do this? Do I use a `post_save` (Post create?) signal?

Comment: You can use `post_save`, although given the number of ratings is not that large, you can also remove the `average_rating` field, and calculate this when you query for `Product`s (so `.annotate(..)` the `Product`s). This is safer, since for example if a rating is removed, or updated, then the average needs to be recalculated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way to do this? Do I use a post_save (Post create?) signal?

The problem is not that much here how to do this technically I think, but more how you make this *robust*. After all it is not only creating new ratings that is important: if people change their rating, or remove a rating, then the average rating needs to be updated as well. It is even possible that if you define a `ForeignKey` with a cascade, then deleting something related to a `Rating` can result in removing several ratings, and thus updating several `Product`s. So getting the average in sync can become quite hard. Especially if you would allow other programs to manipulate the database.

It might therefore be better to calculate the average rating. For example with an aggregate:

```
from django.db.models import Avg

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @property
    def average_rating(self):
        return self.ratings.aggregate(average_rating=Avg('rating'))['average_rating']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Or if you want to load multiple `Product`s in a `QuerySet`, you can do an `.annotate(..)` to calculate the average rating in bulk:

```
Product.objects.annotate(
    average_rating=Avg('rating__rating')
)
```

Here the `Product`s will have an attribute `average_rating` that is the average rating of the *related* ratings.

In case the number of ratings can be huge, it can take considerable time to calculate the average. In that case I propose to add a field, and use a periodic task to *update* the rating. For example:

```
from django.db.models import Avg, OuterRef, Subquery

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    avg_rating=models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=3,
        decimal_places=2,
        null=True,
        default=None
    )

    @property
    def average_rating(self):
        return self.avg_rating or self.ratings.aggregate(average_rating=Avg('rating'))['average_rating']

    @classmethod
    def update_averages(cls):
        subq = cls.objects.filter(
            id=OuterRef('id')
        ).annotate(
            avg=Avg('rating__rating')
        ).values('avg')[:1]
        cls.objects.update(
            avg_rating=Subquery(subq)
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

You can then periodically call `Product.update_averages()` to update the average ratings of *all* products. In case you create, update, or remove a rating, then you can aim to set the `avg_rating` field of the related product(s) to `None` to force recalculation, for example with a `post_save`, etc. But note that signals can be circumveted (for example with the `.update(..)` of a queryset, or by `bulk_create(..)`), and thus that it is still a good idea to periodically synchronize the average ratings.

Comment: Hi Willem, thanks for the detailed and thorough response! I have added the aggregate method to my model (@property), but I don't see the average_rating field when I'm looking at my /api/products on the admin panel? How can I make that field visible in the admin panel and make my API return that average_rating on GET to /products ?

Comment: @noobprogrammer: you need to add an extra field in the serializer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36697562/67579