# DjangoREST annotate count of related entries with filtering

Tags: django, orm, django-rest-framework

So I'm doing a little project in Django REST, and I'm still getting used to the ORM. I'm dealing with the following Django model:

```
class Session(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now, blank=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='efforts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'm particularly interested in the number of session each owner has, given a specific month. As follows:

```
Session.objects.filter(date__gte=start, date__lt=end).values('owner').annotate(num_sessions=Count('owner')).order_by("owner")
```

This query produces results of the following structure:

```
(owner, count)
```

In the serializer, I'd like to use the owner to retrieve the user name, as to structure the response. I'm having absolutely no luck in doing so. My serializer looks like this at the moment:

```
class SessionAggregateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    num_sessions = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    owner = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Session
        fields = ('id', 'owner', 'num_sessions')
```

Anyone any suggestions on how to approach this? For regular queries, I'm using the following line to retrieve the users' name, but this is no longer applicable in the current setting:

```
owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
```

Comment: I think it's more concise to use `<owner>.efforts.count()` instead of your annotate function if you are just retrieving one record at a time.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I'm amazed by how awkward the ORM feels to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to make the use-case more concrete:

Sessions are attached to users, via the 'efforts' relationship. Given a start and end time, I wanted to display a list for the users along with then number of sessions---with a date between the start and end date---attached to them. Sessions are further identified by a branch. This is the same for users, however users may belong to multiple branches. Therefore, the count should be further drilled down to take solely sessions into a count with a branch that appears in the branches for the requestors' user object. Furthermore, users with a session-count of zero should be omitted to keep the result concise.

The Session model looks as follows:

```
class Session(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now, blank=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='efforts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, related_name='hour_branch', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=1, blank=False, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(3)])
```

The User model looks as follows (left out various fields for brevity).

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    branches = models.ManyToManyField(Branch)
```

The answer above was unsatisfactory, as it did not allow me to filter the sessions that are taken into a count for the user as desired. Hence why I ended up with the following solution, using a [conditional expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/conditional-expressions/):

Code for the view in question:

```
class AggregateSessionList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSessionsSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        today=datetime.date.today()
        month=self.request.query_params.get('month', today.month)
        year=self.request.query_params.get('year', today.year)

        start = datetime.date(year=year, month=month, day=1)
        end = datetime.datetime(year=start.year + int(start.month / 12), month=int((start.month % 12) + 1), day=1)

        branches = self.request.user.branches.all()
        return User.objects.annotate(
            sessions=Count(Case(
                When(efforts__date__gt=start, efforts__date__lt=end, efforts__branch__in=branches, then=1),
                output_field=IntegerField()))).filter(sessions__gt=0)
```

Code for the serializer:

```
class UserSessionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sessions = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'sessions')
```

Thought i'd share this solution as I couldn't find anything similar.

### EDIT

An additional benefit from this solution in favor of ruddra's answer, is that only a single DB query is executed. This in contrast to ruddra's answer where an additional query is executed for each user (which is not feasibly for my requirements).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `SerializerMethodField`([documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)):

```
class SessionAggregateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        ...
        username = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
        class Meta:
            model = Session
            fields = ('id', 'username', 'num_sessions')

        def get_username(self, obj):
          return obj.owner.username
```

#### Update

```
   class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        ...
        sessions = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('id', 'username', 'sessions')

        def get_sessions(self, obj):
          return obj.efforts.all().count()  # or obj.efforts.filter(efforts__date__gte=....).count()
```

Comment: Produces the AttributedError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'owner'.

Comment: Thats weird. because `obj` should the instance of the Model. Are you passing `Session.objects.values()` through the `SessionAggregateSerializer`? (if you do, then you should pass `Session.objects.all()` instead)

Comment: Yes, the exact query listed above is returned by the get_queryset function in the API view.

Comment: okay maybe you can drop `.values('owner')` from the queryset metioned in the question and use it in `get_queryset` method.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, I'm using the .values() to obtain an aggregate result per owner. And for the given 'owner' (which is a user_id) I want to obtain the username (which is stored in a separate table)

Comment: You don't need that if you are serializing it via Django rest framework. Please see this SO answer as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36697562/2696165

Comment: The example provided in the SO departs from the Books table, and follows the relation (this is the same as starting from the user relation in my case). Due to the filtering i'm doing (which is not all included above) this is not applicable for me.

Comment: filtering returns a queryset. So it should not be problem.

Comment: I could indeed start from the user model, and expand the sessions from there (as is the case with the books example). The problem with this is, that the 'count' i'm willing to show, is not a global one, as it is the case with the said example. The count is tailored to a user-given month and to the session type as well (which was not included in the MWE for conciseness.). Thus, starting from the user-relation and expanding the 'efforts', does not allow me to subsequently filter out the sessions that are not of interest. Hence why I started from the sessions in the first place.

Comment: actually you could filter out those sessions as well. It can also be done through `methodserializer`.

Comment: Could you provided a small example for this? Expending the 'efforts' from the User, as: User.objects.annotate(sessions=Count('efforts')). How would I include the fields needed for the filtering in the resulting queryset? Wow this ORM feels so awkward to me.

Comment: Thanks master! Had to add some serializer context to make it work, but it did the job. Thank you very much!

Comment: Awesome :) also will appropriate an upvote as well. :D

Comment: Use something like this: `User.objects.annotate(sessions=Count('efforts__id')).filter(sessions__gt=0)`

Comment: May I ask, if is there anything wrong with my solution? thanks

Comment: Posted another answer myself.

Comment: Thing is that, as far as I know `sessions = serializers.IntegerField()` is also writeable. means you should be able to pass values in sessions field. So pass `read_only=True`. Also my answer will work as well. If you annotate sessions value, then it should get `obj.sessions` in return. anyways, happy coding :)

Comment: That's probably true, the main issue with that solution is (if i'm not mistaken) that doing additional filtering in the serializer will issue additional, separate database queries. This implies that a query is executed for each user, which is not really efficient. The construct in my answer will execute a single query, therefore reducing significant overhead. Still thanks for your time/answers, you got me on the right track anyways.