# How to retrieve all usernames alongside a boolean flag for each user to indicate their membership to a group?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to build a page which allows the admin user to toggle membership to a particular group for each user. I aim to do this with AJAX functionality. I am using Django 2.2.

I have implemented an AJAX call which returns all users in the system - this data populates a [data table](https://datatables.net). The next step is to have a checkbox next to each user, indicating their membership to a group.

I am using the code below in my view to retrieve users.

```py
users = list(GeminiUser.objects.filter(is_active=1).values('email'))
```

I want the users query result to contain a boolean field for each user indicating their membership to a particular group. How can I achieve this?

Appreciate any guidance.

Comment: What Django version are you using?

Comment: I am using Django version 2.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do this with a *subquery* and with an [**`Exists`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries):

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

in_group = Group.objects.filter(
    pk=mygroup.pk,
    user=OuterRef('pk')
)

my_users = User.objects.annotate(in_group=Exists(in_group))
```

with `mygroup.pk` the primary key of the group for which you want to check membership.

This queryset contains `User` objects with an extra attribute `in_group` that is `True` if the user belongs to the group, and `False` otherwise.

For example:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User
>>> mygroup = Group.objects.first()
>>> from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef
>>> 
>>> in_group = Group.objects.filter(
...      pk=mygroup.pk,
...      user=OuterRef('pk')
... )
>>> 
>>> my_users = User.objects.annotate(in_group=Exists(in_group))
>>> my_users
<QuerySet [<User: >, <User: test>]>
>>> [u.in_group for u in my_users]
[True, False]
```

You can perform extra filtering on the queryset as well, such that it for example only shows active users, etc.

As for the serialization, please use a *serializer* [[Django REST framework doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) [[Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#serializing-django-objects). Using `.values()` is not recommended at all. By separating the query and representation, you make it easier to extend, update, etc. your REST views.

Comment: @Mr.B: did you define an m2m relation to the/a `Group` model? You should use the `related_name` instead of `user` in `user=...`.

Comment: Yep - it's working as expected I just overlooked something. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: How can I get the serializer to also contain the in_group property? I a tried specifiying 'in_group' as a field to serializer but to no avail.

Comment: @MrB: you can specify it with a `read_only`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18435414/67579

Comment: Does that mean I have to create a serializer class for the users model?

Comment: @MrB: typically it is indeed advisable to make a serializer for entities you wish to transfer yes.